# How to make matplotlib NOT "MSD sort" (1,10,100,11,12....) x-axis in histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a histogram from a 1D array using matplotlib, and while the input file is sorted numerically (1,1,2,2,2,3...200), which is naturally how I'd like the x-axis to look as well - the x-axis of the histogram is sorted by the most significant digit (1,10,100,2,20,200,3...).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("file.txt") as occurences_file:
    list = [l.rstrip() for l in occurences_file.readlines()]

plt.hist(list, bins = 50, log = True)
```

This problem persists without log scale.

How do I prevent the x-axis from being sorted by MSD?

Comment: I haven't played with matplotlib, but have you tried parsing the inputs with `int()`?

Comment: @Sperbat this is almost certainly because your x values are strings, not integers

Comment: You are both completely right. Thank you!!